Export/Import Blog Post from and to sites with different themes?
I've got a Multisites Wordpress Instance running on my server. On there I've got a Wordpress Site which uses the Avada Theme and on that site I've got about 200+ Blogposts. Now it was decided to rebuild the site completely on a new domain using the Hello Elementor Theme and I wanted to import the Blogposts from the old page to the new page. Unfortunately all the Blogposts from the Avada Theme Site look horrible when importing them to the Elementor Theme Site. So I wanted to ask if someone knows an easy solution on how to fix that without having to open every single blogpost and fix them by hand?
Appreciate any answer!

Avada and Elementor are using different page builders so when you are switching between them the UI of the blog posts get distracted so we need to made changes per post wise.
